# How Language(except Go) is corresponded to Bluemix Block Chain?

Tags: java, python, ibm-cloud, blockchain

How Language(except Go) is corresponded to Bluemix Block Chain ?

I want to use Python or Java or so on in developing Blockchain service.

Comment: Your question is so general that it will not likely find an answer here. A good place to start would be the Bluemix Blockchain documentation. Once you have a specific question about something you are doing while developing a Blockchain service, you can find an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

For interacting with a blockchain network, there is the [Hyperleder Fabric Client for Node.js](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/etn_sdk.html).  This SDK can be used for operations such as deploying, invoking, and querying chaincode.  Hyperledger Fabric version 1.0 is currently under development and work is being done on a [Java SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java).

Chaincode can also be written in Java, but this has not been used very much with Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.1.  There is a limitation that Java chaincode will not work with a security-enabled blockchain network when using this version.